# Setting specific mac address in docker

Tags: linux, docker, mac-address, lxc

I'm trying to set a specific mac address in docker using the following command but it's not working

```
docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.network.hwaddr=ec:g6:bb:98:9c:d3" -i -t 0d14
```

anyone see anything wrong with the command above ?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479242/how-to-set-the-mac-address-for-docker-lxc-containers)?

Comment: yeah, i'm saw it, i'm trying to figure how to pass the environment variable

Comment: -e lxc is not an environment variable it's an option for docker service in /etc/default/docker